# Multi threaded resource GPU submit

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool, vulkan

I'm tinkering with Vulkan and I've stumbled on an issue: Thread pools and resource submission.

My current code does not cause validation layer errors or faults in program exit (i.e. allocations etc), but the textures I'm using in the app are faulty - in my current case it is simply solid pink, and not the Stormtrooper helmet I was expecting

I'm using [this threadpool library](https://github.com/vit-vit/ctpl) to handle pooling where I've renamed the class to fit my code style.

For reference, by simply loading an image with Image::Image("my/texture/dir/texture.png") and Image::invalidate(), everything works. This use case does not consume a command buffer, but asks for a command buffer from my global context.

I'm guessing that I've misunderstood something fundamental, and would love to be schooled:

```
void ImageCache<T>::load_from_directory(const std::filesystem::path& shader_directory) {
    auto sorted_images_in_directory
        = IO::in_directory<std::string>(shader_directory, { ".tga", ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg" }, true);

    ThreadPool pool { 8 };
    std::mutex mutex;
    buffer->begin();
    for (const auto& entry : sorted_images_in_directory) {
        const auto image_name = remove_extension<std::filesystem::path>(entry);
        ImageProps props { .path = entry };
        // Load all images and obtain pixels from image data (png, jpg etc)
        Image image = Image(props);
        // Push a function into the thread pool which should:
        pool.push([&images = images, &buffer = buffer, image_name, &image, &mutex](int) {
            std::unique_lock lock(mutex); // Lock the mutex

            // This is the work horse:
            // Submit into the common (for all images) VkCommandBuffer
            // 1) Move pixel data of image to staging buffer,
            // 2) create VkImage.
            // 3) transition image from undefined to dst_optimal (in same CB)
            // 4) copy pixel data from staging to VkImage (in same CB)
            // 5) transition from dst_optimal to shader_read_optimal (in same CB)
            // 6) Create VkImageView and VkSampler
            image.invalidate(buffer);
            // invalidate also adds a 'destructor' callback to the command buffer, which
            // just prior to vkQueueSubmit deallocates the staging buffer, like so:
            // buffer->add_destruction_callback([&staging_buffer_allocation, &staging_buffer]
            //  (Allocator& allocator) { allocator.destroy_buffer(staging_buffer, staging_buffer_allocation); });

            images.try_emplace(image_name, image); // Push into image/texture cache

            lock.unlock(); // Unlock the mux
        });
    }
    pool.stop();
    buffer->end();
    buffer->submit();
}
```

Comment: You don't give much to go on. Even the little code given is heavily abstracted and intervowen with some pseudocode\prose.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment, not a whole lot to go on here. But some things I'd look at:

- Verify the command-buffer is being submitted from the appropriate thread. Whilst you can record command buffers from any thread, you should synchronize submission (generally from the primary thread).
- I'm assuming you're recording multiple command buffers. Verify your submission order is correct (i.e. you're submitting the buffer that fills the image before the buffer that consumes it).
- It's hard to tell from your pseudocode, but I suspect you might have a threading bug around the image collection itself. You're grabbing the mutex at the start, but then (maybe?) spawning a thread per image. Each thread should hold the mutex before accessing any collection object. So your try_emplace should be guarded, at least.

But again, without real code here, it's hard to tell exactly what the root cause might be. I do think a threading bug around collections is the most likely culprit from what you're observing.